# Operator overloading error?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I keep getting an compiler error with my program in Visual Studio Express 13
I commented the 2 lines in my code where the compiler error is showing up

Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date(int d, int m, int y) : day(d), month(m), year(y)
{}

Date::Date() : day(0), month(0), year(0)
{}

const int Date::getDay() { return day; }

const int Date::getMonth() { return month; }

const int Date::getYear(){ return year; }

bool Date::operator<(const Date dOther)
{
    return (year < dOther.year) || (year == dOther.year && month < dOther.month)
        || (year == dOther.year && month == dOther.month && day < dOther.day);
}

string Date::toString()   //Error: Declaration is incompatible with...declared at line 21...Date.h
{
    string s = month + "-" + day; s+="-" + year;
    return s;
}


ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& out, Date& d) 
{
    string s = d.toString();
    out.write(s.c_str(), s.size());         
    return out;
}

void Date::operator=(string s) //no instance of overloaded function "Date::operator=" matches the specified type
{
    stringstream stream;
    stream << s;
    stream >> month;
    stream >> day;
    stream >> year;
}
```

Date.h

```
#ifndef DATE_CLASS
#define DATE_CLASS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class Date
{
private:
int day, month, year;

public:
Date();
Date(int, int, int);

const int getDay();
const int getMonth();
const int getYear();

string toString();        
bool operator<(const Date);

friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& out, Date&d);


void operator=(string);

}; 

#endif
```

I have no idea why these errors are showing up.  Is it a problem with operator overloading? or something with visual studio(for some reason if I delete some code in Date.cpp, the compiler errors disappear)?

Comment: You should really be using `const` on your member functions where appropriate, not returning `const` things, and having `operator=` return a `Date &`. Also making `operator<<` take a `const Date &` and not be a friend since it doesn't need to be here. And probably just doing `out << s;` and taking a `std::ostream &` so it works with more than just files.

Comment: Is this your exact code? There should be errors in your header file. No `std::` anywhere.

Comment: @chris Why should `operator<<` not be a friend function? I thought that since the since the function's first parameter is a `ostream`, I would need to make the function a friend to directly change a Date object's member variables

Comment: @awesomeyi For some reason, before there were no errors in the header file, but now if I remove the `std::` prefix, the errors show up

Comment: @AmitS, But you aren't accessing any of the private `Date` stuff in it, so there's no point in it being able to access that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have namespaces mismatch. In the header you do not use the `std` namespace prefix before `string` thus the compiler can't find the type `string` that you need.

Comment: Makes me wonder what horrors are in the main file or some other one.

Comment: @awesomeyi `ofstream` is used by reference in the header and actual access to its internals occurs after the `toString` implementation. Could be compiler being more easy with reference types and not attempting to evaluate them before actual use (or the OP just didn't include other errors...)

Comment: @icepack Thanks, I now realize that the `string` in my header file was not the same as the `std::string` in my .cpp file.  I put `using namespace std` as a quick fix in my header file, and the code compiles!(but i will remove that statement and use the prefix)